# dataLayer и пространство имен

Tags: javascript

Приветик!
Кто знает, не разрушается ли объект **dataLayer**, инициированный на главной странице сайта (глобальная область, насколько я понимаю) и напичкан в процессе передвижения пользователей по сайту данными типа имя, имейл, названия продуктов и прочее, а затем пользователь нажимает кнопку "Купить", попадает на домен финансового процессора, оплачивает и возвращается на страницу благодарности того же домена, где начинал выбирать, оформлять заказ.
Будет ли глобальный объект dataLayer еще существовать в том виде и с теми данными, которые он держал в себе до перехода на домен финпроцессора?